# Track Navigation in Android Webview

Tags: android, cordova, adb

I'm wondering if there are any good tools for analyzing the navigation of an android application within a web view or within something like Cordova.

If an android application is changing states, is there a good tool to determine, for example the underlying URL that the application is currently on or was previously on? I'm doing an analysis of an already built android application and part of the requirements is to see what URL's the application navigates to but this isn't visible from the application itself. I only have the APK.

Perhaps ADB has this functionality or there are some third party tools available?

Comment: What about connecting the device to the same network and do some network sniffing? For example with Wireshark

Comment: Yeah wireshark would be what I'd go with if there's no simpler solution. Just rather not have to filter through all the other stuff that wire shark might pull.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best tool is Chrome inspector: just type `chrome://inspect` in Chrome's address bar and connect to your device. Please note that your APK must be compiled in debug mode.

Comment: I'm going to try that! Thanks!